# With clause : nesting trees

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

I have a tree hierarchy with sibling ordering. I need to add a reference to other trees.

Here is the data :

```
drop table if exists org; CREATE TABLE org(id int primary key, name text, boss int, sibling int, ref int) without rowid;
INSERT INTO org VALUES(0, 'Alice', NULL, null, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(1, 'Bob', 0, null, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(2, 'Cindy', 0, 1, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(3, 'Dave', 1, 4, 7);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(4, 'Emma', 1, null, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(5, 'Fred', 2, null, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(6, 'Gail', 2, 5, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(7, 'Helen', NULL, null, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(8, 'Igor', 7, null, null);
INSERT INTO org VALUES(9, 'Jerome', 7, 8, null);
```

Dave references the tree lead by Helen.

I added the refs clause :

```
WITH RECURSIVE
refs(id, name, boss, sibling, ref, lref) AS (
 SELECT id, name, boss, sibling, ref, 0 FROM org
UNION ALL
 SELECT org.id, org.name, org.boss, org.sibling, org.ref, refs.lref+1
 FROM org JOIN refs ON org.id=refs.ref
),
sibs(id, name, boss, lref, lsib) AS (
 SELECT id, name, boss, lref, 0 FROM refs
 WHERE sibling IS NULL
UNION ALL
 SELECT refs.id, refs.name, refs.boss, refs.lref, sibs.lsib + 1
 FROM refs
 JOIN sibs ON refs.boss = sibs.boss
 AND refs.sibling = sibs.id
),
tree(id, name, lsib, lref, level) AS (
 select id, name, 0, 0, 0 from org where id = 0
UNION ALL
 SELECT sibs.id, sibs.name, sibs.lsib, sibs.lref, tree.level+1
 FROM sibs JOIN tree ON sibs.boss=tree.id
ORDER BY 4 DESC, 5 DESC, 3 DESC
)
SELECT group_concat(name) FROM tree;
```

But the result doesn't include Helen's tree:

> Alice,Cindy,Gail,Fred,Bob,Dave,Emma

How can I get the complete result with Helen's tree :

> Alice,Cindy,Gail,Fred,Bob,Dave,Helen,Igor,Jerome,Emma

**EDIT :**

Bob and Cindy -and Fred&Gail- were inverted ... Actual expected result is :

> Alice,Bob,Dave,Helen,Igor,Jerome,Emma,Cindy,Fred,Gail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the following expected output:

> Alice,Cindy,Gail,Fred,Bob,Dave,Helen,Igor,Jerome,Emma

Because you are asking for different result for the same case:

- Cindy and Bob : same parent. Cindy is sibling with Bob and you want Cindy before bob.
- Jerome and Igor: same parent. Jerome is sibling with Igor and you want Igor before Jerome.

**(If Cindy must be printed before Bob then Jerome must be printed before Igor)**

I think the expected output should be:

> Alice,Cindy,Gail,Fred,Bob,Dave,Helen,Jerome,Igor,Emma

OR

> Alice,Bob,Dave,Helen,Igor,Jerome,Emma,Cindy,Fred,Gail

---

### First method

I tried the following query *(use refs.id instead of org.boss)*:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
refs(id, name, boss, sibling, ref, lref) AS (
 SELECT id, name, boss, sibling, ref, 0 FROM org

UNION ALL
 SELECT org.id, org.name, refs.id, org.sibling, org.ref, refs.lref+1
 FROM org JOIN refs ON org.id=refs.ref
),
sibs(id, name, boss, lref, lsib,ref) AS (
 SELECT id, name, boss, refs.lref, 0,ref FROM refs
  WHERE sibling IS NULL
UNION ALL
 SELECT refs.id, refs.name, refs.boss, refs.lref, sibs.lsib + 1,refs.ref
 FROM refs
 JOIN sibs ON refs.boss = sibs.boss
 AND refs.sibling = sibs.id
),
tree(id, name, lsib, lref, level) AS (
 select org.id, org.name, 0, 0, 0 from org 
  where id = 0

UNION ALL
 SELECT sibs.id, sibs.name, sibs.lsib, sibs.lref, tree.level+1
 FROM sibs JOIN tree ON sibs.boss = tree.id 
ORDER BY  4 DESC, 5 DESC
)
select group_concat(name) from tree;
```

> Alice,Bob,Dave,Helen,Igor,Jerome,Emma,Cindy,Fred,Gail

### Second method

I used a different approach:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
pc(id,name,parent,priority) AS(
  select org.id,org.name,coalesce(refs.id,org.boss,-1) as "parent",
  case
  when refs.id is not null then 3
  when sibls.id is not null then 2
  when org.boss is not null then 1
  else 0 end as  "priority"
  from org left join org as refs on org.id = refs.ref
  left join org as sibls on org.id = sibls.sibling
where org.id > 0),
  tree(id,name,parent,priority,level) AS(
    select id,name,0,0,0 from org where id = 0
    UNION ALL
    select pc.id,pc.name,pc.parent,pc.priority,tree.level + 1 from pc 
    join tree on tree.id = pc.parent
    order by 3 desc )
    select group_concat(name) from tree
```

> Alice,Bob,Dave,Helen,Igor,Jerome,Emma,Cindy,Fred,Gail

Comment: Bob and Cindy were inverted ... could you update with that correction ?

Comment: @Simon i updated both methods. Note that Fred and Gail also must be inverted since they follow the same rule

Comment: @Simon you can also check the first one, i added SQLFiddle link but i don't know why they are not working well in my browser.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work in my browser as well. Anyway that's good thank you for your help!

Comment: @Simon Ok. I removed the links since they are not working. It looks like SQLFiddle have problems with SQLite engine. Good Luck

Comment: (I just saw the 250 were not credited automatically when the good solution is selected, so I validated them now)

Comment: @Simon thanks. I wrote the comment since i received a downvote without any comment. It is not about the bounty. When you accept an answer the bounty will be awarded automatically when its period will end.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
      FROM org
      START WITH boss is null 
      CONNECT BY PRIOR id= boss
      ORDER SIBLINGS BY sibling;
```

required output:

```
Alice, Bob, Cindy, Dave, Emma, Fred, Gail, Helen, Igor, Jerome
```

Comment: It is not giving the expected output